# Rails Capybara Spec not detecting display: none

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I'm writing a Capybara spec and trying to detect whether something is visible or not.  The following spec is passing and it shouldn't be, because #packages is display: none.

```
  it "should navigate through marketing successfully" do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Learn More'
    page.should have_content 'We are the perfect match'
    click_link 'Packages'
    page.should have_selector('#packages', visible: true)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the show/hide functionality using javascript or jQuery it's not going to be picked up by Capybara/RSpec because it's not necessarily running a full browser.

The Capybara docs go some way to explaining how to test methods that require JavaScript here ..
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using JS to do that.  I have other tests using JS, but this one (I think) doesn't need it because it's hidden on page load.